# Python Pandas Group By Consecutive Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need to do a consecutive group-by involving multiple columns in a pandas dataframe.  I've found answers on how to do a consecutive group-by with a single column, but I'm not sure how to extend it to multiple columns.

For exmaple, my data looks like:

```
    Time     Object   Status                           
    1        A       On 
    2        A       Off
    3        A       On
    4        B       On
    5        B       On
```

I want to count consecutive observations with the same Object and Status.

```
    Object    Status    Duration
1   A         On        1
2   A         Off       1
3   A         On        1                       ,
4   B         On        2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the "consecutiveness" condition, compare each row with its succeeding row.
When they are not equal, we wish to start a new group:

```
mask = (df[['Object','Status']] != df[['Object','Status']].shift(1)).any(axis=1)
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3     True
# 4    False
# dtype: bool

group = mask.cumsum()
# 0    1
# 1    2
# 2    3
# 3    4
# 4    4
# dtype: int64
```

Now you can group `df` by the `group`, `Object` and `Status` and aggregate by `count`:

```
df.groupby([group, df['Object'], df['Status']], as_index=False).agg('count')
#   Object Status  Time
# 0      A     On     1
# 1      A    Off     1
# 2      A     On     1
# 3      B     On     2
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Status': ['On', 'Off', 'On', 'On', 'On'],
                   'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
mask = (df[['Object','Status']] != df[['Object','Status']].shift(1)).any(axis=1)
group = mask.cumsum()
result = df.groupby([group, df['Object'], df['Status']], as_index=False).agg('count')
result = result.rename(columns={'Time':'Duration'})
print(result)
```

yields

```
  Object Status  Duration
0      A     On         1
1      A    Off         1
2      A     On         1
3      B     On         2
```